# Is it grammatically correct to say 'the outfit is relaxed'?

Tags: meaning

One of my students while describing a person in the coursebook said that 'her outfit is relaxed'. I doubt whether one can actually say so, but she insists that she came across the exact phrase in one of the blogs by a British writer.

I checked the meaning of *relaxed* in Macmillan English Dictionary for Advanced Learners New Edition (2007) and found out the following: 
'relaxed 1) calm and not worried 2) a relaxed situation, attitude, or feeling is calm, informal, and comfortable' - no reference to clothes whatsoever.

Comment: The style of her outfit is relaxed. Or you can say "She adopts a relaxed style which is reflected in her wardrobe."

Comment: There are two senses of "relaxed' clothing in U.S. English, and perhaps elsewhere in the English-speaking world: (1) casual as opposed to formal wear may be characterized as "relaxed"; (2) clothing that is cut to be roomier for the wearer to fit into may be called "relaxed-cut" clothing.

Answer (score 2):

[Relaxed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relaxed) outfit:

> - not strict; easy; informal.

The Free Dictionary

- There is a lot about it on the web: [relaxed outfit](https://www.google.it/#q=relaxed+outfit).

Comment: There are lots of things on the internet nowadays.. the question is to what extent it is grammatically/lexically correct. I would prefer a more reliable source than the free dictionary which I know nothing about. @Josh61

Comment: I do check meanings of some phrases in the Urban Dictionary, let's say, but that doesn't mean it is a reliable source as anyone is free to write any definition he/she thinks appropriate there. @Josh61

Comment: @Yukatan - relaxed: *somewhat loose-fitting and usually casual in style* (***relaxed jeans***). http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relaxed

Comment: Also, Yukatan, how about doing your homework and checking Google Books, which is mainly edited and native stuff, to see magazine articles from Ebony to Esquire, mentioning the  usage? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22+Relaxed+outfit%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22Relaxed+outfit%22 Demanding, demanding, but not doing the work, eh? And do you think that all the merchandising is lexically and grammatically correct? No, but it's out there and sticks, like this one.